# IOS native controls invisible/hidden in PWA

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

We have a PWA (web app) that the user can add to the homescreen to make it look more like an app. Some users have reported a strange issue that only seems to appear on IOS sometimes when the following step has been made.

1. Open the app from the homescreen
2. Use the app for a while
3. Put it into background
4. Turn off the screen for a while
5. Turn the screen back on and put the app to foreground again

The bug is that nothing seems to happen when you click on a select or date input control. First I thought that there was some overlay in the app that was blocking the ui controls but the elements receive focus on click, but not options are shown.

Now it really becomes strange. When I tried to click a little bit under the select input an option was selected. The same thing occured with a time select. If I first clicked on the timeselect input control and then a little bit under, it updated the time.

So, the controls seems to be there but nothing is visible on the screen. I have only been able to reproduce this on my own once but multiple users have been reporting the same thing. The only way to work around the bug is to restart the app.

It seems to be for all native safari controls that shows some kind of modal/popover.

[image: gif showing the issue]

Comment: Having the same problem. Is this an iOS bug. Any progress?

Comment: Not any progress so far. We have only been able to reproduce on IOS after it has been added to homescreen. Is that the case for you aswell or does it also happen when browsing in the "regular" browser?

Comment: It's the same for us, only when we've added it to the homescreen and left it idle for a while. Works flawlessly with the "regular" browser.

Comment: Thanks, nice to not be alone with the issue at least. Have you had the issue for a long time or is it new?

Comment: It's about a month old. Can't seem to find a way around it I'm afraid.

Comment: ok, and your app is older than one month? Ours is completely new so it has been hard for us to know if it is related to our app or something that is broken in safari.

Comment: It is. This bug started when they changed how the dropdown works. A few months ago or less.

Answer (score 2):

I've did an indepth investigation on this select dropdown problem and posted an issue at bugs.webkit.org: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238318

It's a problem with dropdowns of several components (such as select, input file/date/month) where either the animation to have the dropdown appear or disappear seems to get stuck. You can sometimes see the dropdown being tiny and very transparent (if you zoom into a screenshot) and sometimes you'll be able to select an option even though you don't see the dropdown.